# Load iptables rules on boot

Tags: boot, server, iptables, firewall, persistence

I use Ubuntu 20 (server) and I made some iptables rules, but they are not loaded after reboot, so I installed package `iptables-persistent`, then using `iptables-save` I saved current rules using command `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`, and after reboot I ran command `iptables -L` and they are empty.

I double checked file `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and it contains rules.

Comment: Just to confirm your rules work, can you run `sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4` just to see what the output is?  If there's an error in the iptables rules it will not load at boot and suppress the error message, but manually doing what iptables-persistent does will help to debug this further.

Comment: Ah thanks, I had error `iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): error creating chain 'DROP':File exists` because I created another chain named `DROP` :D thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I converted my comment to an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, if your rules work when you add them but not in `iptables-persistent` then you've done something wrong in your rules most likely, though `iptables-persistent` suppresses the error.  So let's debug your code.

Run `sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4`.  This will run the same tasks `iptables-persistent` does but will give you error output.  Fix any errors it says and update your iptables rules files, then it'll work next reboot.

In your comments, you tried to create the chain named DROP, but you cannot create a chain that is named as a protected target.  DROP, REJECT, ACCEPT, etc. are protected chain names.